# How can I access "local" variables declared outside Polymer({ ... })?

Tags: javascript, polymer, require

I am using require1k to be able to read some 3rd libraries which uses CommonJS module structure. In the script tag of my polymer element I have:

```
<SCRIPT>
  R(function(require, module, export) {

    var foo = require('./modules/foo');

    Polymer({
      is: 'test-element',
      ...
      ready: function() {
        console.log('foo test: ' + foo.test()); // TypeError call test of undefined 
      }
    });
  });
</SCRIPT>
```

Something like that.

I though that everything within Polymer would be able access the foo variable declared in the R-function... but obviously not.

What is the common (prefered) way in Polymer to handle 3rd party dependencies?

Comment: Have you tried passing the data into your Polymer element as a property?

Comment: Thanks. That didn't solve it for me, but I started digging into the code again and... I accidently wrote exports.module in my modules/foo script, it should have been module.exports. So now it works :)